# How to change url in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Check this url http://www.angelicalgifts.com/blog/

On this site top right there is a About page link..I need to change the full url of this about page link..How we do this in wordpress?

Comment: Can you post the code that generates that nabvar?

Answer (score 1):

In the Admin panel, go into Appearance -> Menus. You will see About menu item there and you can change the URL.